# Flutter/Dart : Parent Class with a list of Children, how can we make child aware of it's parent?

Tags: class, flutter, dart

So a simple parent/child class structure.

```
class Parent{
  Parent({this.id, this.children});
  final int id;
  final List<Child> children;
}
class Child{
  Child({this.id, this.parent});
  final int id;
  final Parent parent;
  Parent getParent() => this.parent; //?????????
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Parent p = new Parent(id: 1, children: new List<Child>.from({Child(id:0, parent:p), Child(id:1, parent:p)}));

  Parent childParent = p.children[0].getParent();
}
```

this results in p used before being declared. but in order to do something like

```
Parent p = Parent(id:1);
p.children = new List<Child>.from({Child(id:0, parent:p), Child(id:1, parent:p)}
```

means the p.children can't be final, and part of the constructor, and seems clunky???

So I can't see how to get a reference to the Parent to pass into the child initialisation?
Would seem to be a standard pattern, but struggling.

ta.

**Usecase:**

parent/child structure is in firestore (collection - subcollection). Database service takes the firestore structure and maps it to these custom objects, maintaining the parent/child structure. The resulting object is stored via provider in the root widget (main.dart -> myApp builder)  to give access from any widget.

At some point we have a screen/page which just displays the child, so no widget structure child is the top most widget. I'd then like to show that the child has a parent of.. and a description from the parent. At which point if this was still just referring to the firestore snapshot->data, I could simply call child.parent() and get the parent. I can't seem to see how to replicate that in the custom class mapping?

Comment: Can you elaborate why are you trying to have reference to the parent in the child?

Comment: Certainly can.. useCase added to the question.

Comment: Can you add a field like ID to the parent and add a function `searchById()` to the class which has `ChangeNotifier`? `searchById()` returns the parent with matching id. All the children get a copy of this ID too. So when you have only the child and want to get the data of it's parent, you can simply instantiate the provider and call `searchById()` with the id.

Comment: Extending this a litlle for parent>child>grandchild>greatgrandchild>etc.. the searchById then seems to be onerous due to the top down from the root requirement.

I guess at that point storing a path to parent, rather than id would be logical.

Just seems strange that we can't make the child self-aware of its parent.